# Framebox with long paragraph and line break

Tags: line-breaking, paragraphs, framed

I want to make a border to a paragraph, so I use `\framebox` to do it. But I have a problem that my paragraph is so long, I can't insert a line break and my paragraph cross the frame.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}

\begin{document}
     \framebox[0.9\textwidth]{
        \textbf{Subordinated bond} (Trái phiếu ưu tiên thấp nhất) là một trái phiếu chỉ được hoàn trả tiền sau          khi một số khoản vay khác của người phát hành đã được ưu tiên thanh toán trước. \par
        \textbf{Senior (Trái phiếu ưu tiên ở mức cao)} là những trái phiếu được đảm bảo chặt chẽ hơn, nghĩa là          được ưu tiên thanh toán tiền ở mức cao hơn các loại khác.
        }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please help me fix problem and show me how to create a framebox whose contents are resized following that framebox.

Comment: have a look at `mdframed`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should wrap it in a `\parbox` of fixed width and box it using `\fbox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\begin{document}
\fbox{%
  \parbox{0.9\textwidth}{%
  \textbf{Subordinated bond} (Trái phiếu ưu tiên thấp nhất) là một trái phiếu chỉ được hoàn trả tiền sau          khi một số khoản vay khác của người phát hành đã được ưu tiên thanh toán trước.
  \par
  \textbf{Senior (Trái phiếu ưu tiên ở mức cao)} là những trái phiếu được đảm bảo chặt chẽ hơn, nghĩa là          được ưu tiên thanh toán tiền ở mức cao hơn các loại khác.}%
}
\end{document}
```

`\par` inside a `\framebox` doesn't yield the desired result, but it works inside a `\parbox`.

Answer (score 6):

You could use package `framed`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{framed}
\begin{document}

\noindent Text before text before text before text before text before
text before text before text before text before text before text before
text before text before text before text before text before text before
text before text before

\begin{framed}
  \textbf{Subordinated bond} (Trái phiếu ưu tiên thấp nhất) là một trái
  phiếu chỉ được hoàn trả tiền sau khi một số khoản vay khác của người
  phát hành đã được ưu tiên thanh toán trước.
  \par
  \textbf{Senior (Trái phiếu ưu tiên ở mức cao)} là những trái phiếu
  được đảm bảo chặt chẽ hơn, nghĩa là được ưu tiên thanh toán tiền ở mức
  cao hơn các loại khác.
\end{framed}

\noindent Text after text after text after text after text after text
after text after text after text after text after text after text after
text after text after text after text after text after text after text
after

\end{document}
```

[image: using framed]